# Razer Synapse 3 Installation Error 142

Tags: audio, razer-synapse

I am trying to install Synapse 3 using the installer from Razer's website: https://www.razer.com/synapse-3. I am trying to use Synapse 3 for a BlackShark V2 Pro headset. However, the installer keeps giving me an error code 142.

Image (Installation failed with error code: 142)
[image]

I have not selected any of the extra modules that Synapse offers nor any of the other software offered besides Synapse. I am wondering how to fix this issue as well as whether or not Synapse 3 is required for the headphones to work.

Comment: Using the manual, I have got the audio output to work. Turns out the power button has to be held down to turn on the headset. As such, it seems that Synapse 3 is not required for the headphones to work. However, I am still unsure how to fix the error code 142 problem.

Comment: https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/error-142-razer-synapse.76130/ suggests temporaily disabling your antivirus. What antivirus solution are you using?

Comment: [Try disabling Windows Defender real time protection temporarily](https://insider.razer.com/index.php?threads/error-142-solved.59237/)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, mine kept failing with error 142 until I unplugged the headset. Once I unplugged it, the install completed successfully. (I had also temporarily disabled AV and such, this may not have been necessary.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144293)